# Changing pixel's dimension (raster) on QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, pixel, dimensions

I would like to change the size of the pixels from `2.5` to `10`. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Right click on the layer list - Export - Save as. I thought that it would be easy to find if from the QGIS documentation but I was wrong. Warp without changing the projection and Raster - Conversion - Translate are other options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Raster - Projections - Warp and set output resolution to 10:

[image]