# Resolution unit calculation

Tags: qgis, resolution, correlation

I'm quite new in the field of GIS, currently working with QGIS.
I didn't find a simple overview of the connection/calculation of resolution units yet.

Is it like this (pixel size for QGIS)?

```
~ 1km =  30 arc-sec = 0.0083333 pixel /
~ 5km = 2.5 arc-min = 0.0416666 pixel /
~15km =  15 arc-min = 0.25000000 pixel
```

Is this correlation correct?

Comment: It depends on your CRS, which one are you using (bottom right corner of the QGIS window)?

Comment: I'm using EPSG:4326

Answer (score 3):

There is no a fixed pixel size in GIS realm. Rasters (image files) may have different pixel sizes. Therefore, these equations are not absolute even if it is correct for the pixel of your raster.

For example, 1 pixel may equal 1mm, 1m, 1km or 1000 km depending on different rasters. So, e.g. `~15km =  0.25000000 pixel`, is not absolute.

Besides, `~15km = 15 arc-min` is not always true either. It may correct for many geographic CRS. But it is not correct for many projected CRS, even for equidistant projections because they don't preserve distance in all directions.

Comment: I may not have explained some facts correctly because my English is not perfect. Please correct if it's wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm working with raster files for the whole globe, so the equidistant projection comes into action here I guess. Is there a way to identify the resolution of a .tif file? As far as I got to know, QGIS only presents the pixel size

Comment: You can decrease the pixel size (=increase the resolution) or vice versa. But increasing the resolution generally doesn't increase the raster quality. Please check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/317971/29431) or [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396054/29431).

Comment: Ok, but if I have a raster file, how do I get know its resolution, if I have no information from the source?

Comment: Double click the raster layer in QGIS. In "Information" tab, you can find resolution and pixel size. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Kth.png)

Comment: What do you do when the pixels dimension is not given? It is not listed in the information tab.